# Request failing during the use of testing credit card in Google Pay

Tags: android, google-pay

I have implemented Google Pay feature, but when I insert a test credit card (4242 4242 4242 4242  12/22  123) it returns me the error below, and when I insert a real credit card it works correctly, returning a token:

> Transaction declined: invalid payment method. Learn more
>   [OR-CCSEH-05].

I didn't find anything in their docs about it.

Isn't it possible to use a test credit card in Google Pay even having set environment as test?

```
 mPaymentsClient =
                Wallet.getPaymentsClient(this,
                new Wallet.WalletOptions.Builder()
                .setEnvironment(WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST)
                .build());
```

Answer (score 2):

In their docs it says:

Environment constant for running in the test environment with relaxed application / merchant requirements. This environment is suggested for early development and for easily testing the Wallet SDK.

1. Does not require the application to be uploaded to the Google Play Store.
2. Does not require a Google Pay Developer Profile.
3. It uses production data, but at the end of the transaction you will receive a fake and non chargeable payment credential.
4. The user will see a warning message that the app is not recognized/verified.

It will still verify the card, it doesn't stop card verification. Which means you can't just enter bogus information for testing.

Comment: The problem is that I do not receive the token when this error occurs, it gives me the error mentionated and I can't proceed in my tests, when using a testing card.

Comment: Your post says "it returns me the error below, and when I insert a real credit card it works correctly, returning a token." Are both the error and the real credit card returning the same transaction declined?

Comment: The transaction is declined when I am using a testing card, which is the correct way to test my app in my opinion

Comment: Do both return the error though? Ignore the previous comment it was for another thread.

Answer (score 0):

i've contacted google regarding this case, as i've been facing similar one and upon it's inspection i've received the following reply:

Thanks for being Patient. I apologize for the inconvenience caused.

Upon checking, I understand that you're unable to add testing cards. I would like to inform you that testing cards can't be added to Google Payment profile as payment Method.

Thanks!

upon further investigation by payment service privider i've been assured:

For a bit of context on how Google Pay works to test payments. When you’re using your test mode API keys, the actual details of the card are ignored, and they get replaced with the PSP 4242 test card. To test authentication you will not be able to add the test cards to your Google Pay account however there is a work around for this, you add our 3DS test cards to Chrome and use the PaymentRequest button with them (making sure to choose them, and not Google Pay itself). Unfortunately there is no direct method to testing this in your the app.

so setting WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST at 5th step of their tutorial should be sufficient and then use your real card in google pay. 
https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial